# Dar formato a string con JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Tengo una función con la cual le doy el formato a un string, la consulta es de que otra forma se puede hacer y que se más eficiente.
Actualmente paso el `string` a un `array` con `split()` y apartir de ahí solo concateno en la posición correspondiente.
La siguiente función recibe un string con 11 elementos `00000902000` y simplemente la devuelve con guiones de la siguiente manera `0-000-09-02000`

```
Input:00000902000
Output:0-000-09-02000

 function formatCode(code) {
    let length = code.split('');        
    let formatCode = length[0]+'-'+length[1]+length[2]+length[3]+'-'+length[4]+length[5]+'-'+length[6]+length[7]+length[8]+length[9]+length[10];
    return formatCode;
}
```

Comment: Utilizar librerías externas es una opción?

Comment: si no hay problema si se requiere una librería. Siempre y cuando mejore.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar una expresión regular

```js
var n = "00000902000";
console.log(n.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3-$4"));
```

En tu caso, tu función quedaría

```js
function formatCode(code) {
    return code.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3-$4");
}
```

La mejora de esto es que, si por cualquier motivo, tienes más de 11 caracteres, usando esta expresión no vas a perder los caracteres del final a diferencia de la función inicial de la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa similar a lo que tienes pero con la ventaja de tampoco perder carácteres en caso de que tengas más de 11 es usar [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

> El método slice() extrae una sección de una cadena y devuelve una cadena nueva.

Básicamente le tienes que decir desde dónde iniciará esa sección y dónde termirá a través del índice del carácter (lógica cero). El fin es excluyente por lo que tienes que sumar 1 al fin. Si no le proporcionas un fin, entonces `.slice` devolverá desde el inicio de la sección hasta el fin de la cadena.

```js
const formatCode = (code) => `${code.slice(0,1)}-${code.slice(1,4)}-${code.slice(4,6)}-${code.slice(6)}`;

console.log(formatCode('00000902000'));
console.log(formatCode('12345678901'));
console.log(formatCode('00000902000111'));
```

Adicionalmente cabe mencionar que un string puede ser tratado como un array por lo que en tu solución no haría falta hacer ese `.split`.